# Importfeed function not loading RSS feed entries sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using this sheet and many similar sheets for a long time but I have been facing this issue in many of the sheets. After a few days, the "importfeed" function stops loading the values on to the sheet. When I make a copy of the sheet (new spreadsheet), it instantly shows the values on the new sheet. It is a solution I do not want to use as I am using the script at different places and in that case I will have to change the script id everywhere. Please find the screenshot of the issue attached to this question below:

[image: Image link: Refresh_Imports]

FYI, I am using a code to refresh the "importfeed" function every minute to get latest data. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: That is a known issue of Google Sheets. If you really need the feed to be updated every minute and need that all the time the data is retrieved correctly then it's very likely that Google Sheets is not be right tool for your use case. If you need further help please add a [mcve] including the execution messages logged when the IMPORTFEED function fails, a link to a demo spreadsheet as the problem might be cause to the spreadsheet performance.

Comment: Related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010822/1595451), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20718931/1595451)