# Bug Report: onGmailCompose has stopped populating the event draftMetadata properties on iOS (Android and browers are still OK) in Apps Script add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script, bug-reporting

All "recipients" properties of the "draftMetadata" object passed into "onGmailCompose" stopped coming through (are now missing) on iOS (iPad and iPhone).

My Apps Script code was working perfectly for about a year, since Sep 30  2022.  It has not been changed since that date.
The last successful operation I can find in my logs took place on 2023-11-16 23:44.48 UTC
The first evidence in my logs showing all calls beginning to fail is 2023-11-22 15:49.52 UTC
so whatever was changed in between those above dates appears to have introduced this bug.
My logs show that there has not been any successful iOS operation since the last one on 2023-11-16 23:44.48 UTC

This issue occurs consistently on all iOS devices: Myself and 24 other (paying=P1) customers have tested this on at least 24 unique iPhones and iPads.

There has been no change to any of my apps script code, dependencies, or infrastructure since Sep 30 2022, and, it continues to work flawlessly on all other platforms besides iOS.

I am at wits end here: I've reported this bug more than a dozen times over the last 3 months, and every time I simply get 1 of two outcomes: no response whatsoever, or, google employees telling me I've reported it to the wrong department - followed by no further response.

I'm a paying workspace user, supposedly on a 4-hour response time, so I'm really not sure what to do now: what's the point of offering us support timeframes in hours, when nothing gets even looked-at for months (so far) ?

How to reproduce the problem:-

1. Implement the below code in a gmail add-on Aps Script project.
2. Compose a gmail and add a recipient using a web browser or android
3. Click your add-on's button - observe that the code works OK, then
4. repeat steps 2 and 3 on an iPhone or iPad - observe the newly-broken behavior as described above ( draftMetadata properties are missing on iOS only )

```js
    function onGmailCompose(e,f) {
        if( e.draftMetadata && (!e.draftMetadata.toRecipients.length) && (!e.draftMetadata.ccRecipients.length) && (!e.draftMetadata.bccRecipients.length) ) { 
          // no recipients
          // [ snip ...]
        }
```

The above used to work perfectly (from 2022 up until 2023-11-16) on all platforms - including all web browsers (chrome/firefox/safari on windows/linux/mac) and (via the "gmail app" from its respective stores) all Androids (phones and tablets) and it used to also work on iPhones and iPads.

However now, on iPad and iPhone (latest versions) that line is always happening, even when recipients are specified.  All other platforms still work fine.

A bug has been introduced into the Apple iOS "Gmail App" which incorrectly fails to populate the "draftMetadata" key passed into the onGmailCompose action.

The App I'm using has not been changed since publication (2022-09-30).

Comment: I can see that this issue has been raised through proper channels already at issuetracker.google.com.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "proper channels" - if you mean filing a bug, and watching for 3+ months as nobody whatsoever even looks at the problem, then yeah...  This is posted here in the hope that an actual engineer from google might happen to be reading.  As far as I can tell, the "triage" people are claiming "resolutions" on issues by marking them as "solution provided" when they add any kinds of comments, even though nobody is actually fixing the bug. The one thing I'm certain about: no actual google developers are reading submitted issues this year, probably because of that triage exploit.

Comment: [Edit] to link the tracker here as well.

Comment: @TheMaster - it's not that simple - there's more than a dozen different places which take bug reports, and so-far, none of the are being actioned. Even the issuretracker system itself has multiple different queues which are attended by different teams - one of which (GCP) is unable to solve workspace issues, so I can't link to anything, because there's no indication which *actual* "channel" is the right one.  I'm going to buy the next-level support plan tomorrow and see if that helps.  Also note: google themselves can't/don't tell me how or where to report this bug (I've asked 10 times)

Comment: " I've reported this bug more than a dozen times over the last 3 months" is **not** an exaggeration.  I do have a list of all the links to all the reports - when/if this gets fixed, I'll update here with which one was the one that worked in the end.

Comment: @cnd The correct place would be Google workspace > Google Workspace addons, Currently component: [642720+](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:642720%2B) . See [search component here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/concepts/searches). You can also add an answer with the tracker link for greater visibility on the issue. See sample answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/73854991 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bgoogle-apps-script%5d%20%22%2b1%22%20is%3aa%20url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fissuetracker.google.com%2f&searchOn=3

Comment: Update: purchasing a support subscription seems to have been the wrong approach - none of the options in their ticket entry system are related to Workspace.  642720+ seems the wrong approach too - nothing at all this year has been "fixed" in that component (besides a feature-request that already existed, and one which got resolved as a result of something else having gotten fixed elsewhere).  There's 129 unfixed problems in the queue (only 32 fixed all-time, most of which weren't real bugs or were trivial).  Serious question: How is a business supposed to rely on Google Cloud or Workspace ?

Comment: I just investigated https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues?q=componentid:642720%20%20type:bug - out of the 764 reported bugs, they've only fixed 29 all-time (and only less than a dozen in the last few years) and the majority of the  issues marked "fixed" are irrelevant (documentation or feature-requests or misunderstandings or flukes).  So that's clearly NOT to correct place to report bugs that need to be fixed.